# MP4 Video Format is not supporting by Google TV

Tags: android, video, google-tv

I am developing a Google TV application, and I have downloaded a mp4 format video from the server and stored in app data. I am trying to play that video inside the Google TV from video view, but it showing the alert like "**Can not play the Video**".

The same application working properly in Tablet and mobiles but not working in Google TV emulator and TV device.

Video I am downloading [from this link](http://podcast.20min-tv.ch/podcast/20min/199733.mp4) and storing in application cache memory as secondvideo.mp4.

```
                File clip=new File(getCacheDir(),"secondvideo.mp4");
                if(clip.exists()){
                    video.setVideoPath(clip.getAbsolutePath());


                      video.setMediaController(null);
                      video.requestFocus();
                      video.postInvalidateDelayed(100);
                      video.start();
                      flag=true;
                }
            }else{


            }
```

Comment: mp4 does work on Google TV. please add test url for the mp4 file that you are using and sample code to help debug further.

Comment: also add the Google TV device type and build version.

Comment: Hi Iam using the following code                                                                 File clip=new File(getCacheDir(),"secondvideo.mp4");
     if(clip.exists()){
      //ideo.setVideoPath(clip.getAbsolutePath());
      video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("http://podcast.20min-tv.ch/podcast/20min/199733.mp4"));
       
           video.setMediaController(null);
           video.requestFocus();
           video.postInvalidateDelayed(100);
           video.start();
           flag=true;
     }
    }else{
     showImage();}

Comment: could you provide the test link? the one you pasted in code gives a 404. Also, the code does not seem right. Please follow VideoView or MediaPlayer sample from APIDemos in Android SDK samples.

Comment: You might also want to look at the video player demo for Google TV: https://code.google.com/p/googletv-video-player/

Answer (score 0):

Video doesn't work well in the emulator.
Megha and Dar have given you the right advice.  But in case there is still a question you'll find https://developers.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_media_formats helpful.

Dar's mention of the sample code I wrote is also a good place to look:  https://code.google.com/p/googletv-video-player/

Your video URL has gone dead (404 as Megha pointed out), so I'm not able to review it.